# Drupal 7 – not able to change path in "edit menu link"

Tags: drupal-7

I am building a navigation menu in drupal 7 and in a few of the menu links it is not possible to edit the "path" in the page "Edit menu links" (under Structure -> Menu -> Navigation). Instead there is a fixed path to for ex. "Add new basic page".

These links also have the option "reset" in stead of "delete"... under Structure -> Menus.

I realize that I must have brought this problem on myself, but I am stuck and cannot figure out how to change the path for these menu links.

So I would like to change the "path". Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn off the menu item and create a new one which will fit your need.

Comment: Thanks, that was of course a very simple solution :-). So now I have 4 disabled menu items, and I could of course leave them like that.. but is there a way to just delete them? The only option is "reset" and that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I might be wrong but (without looking deep into it) i suppose that it comes from "menu" module of drupal core, which would be bad practice to edit it. You may also look for some hook to manipulate menu items display but in my opinion better to live it as it is and do much more important stuff. Any way it's just for administrator view so it will not bother your users.

Comment: OK, I will settle for that solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This particular menu item was probably created using views. Go into the view and modify the menu item for the related view under Page settings